# c3.js вывод процентов при наведении в заголовке Donut Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, диаграммы, c3.js

Пытаюсь освоить библиотеку c3.js. Требуется при наведении на пункт диаграммы или легенды, отобразить значение процентов этого пункта вместо заголовка по центру диаграммы. Сейчас там надпись:"тут проценты от label".

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['Поле 1', 5],
      ['Поле 2', 25],
      ['Поле 3', 70],
    ],
    type: 'donut',
    onmouseover: function(d) {
      x = d.value;
      console.log("вернули", x);
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false, // отключаем меню при наведении на столбцы
    title: function(d) {
      return 'Data ' + d;
    },
  },
  donut: {
    label: {
      show: false //отключаем вывод процентов на самих столбцах
    },
    //title: function () {return x + '%'}, // не понятно как обновлять переменную
    title: 'тут проценты от label',

  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pubnub/eon/master/lib/eon.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pubnub/eon/master/lib/eon.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.13.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно делать средствами `jQuery`.
(тег стоит пишу ответ, но можно и без него в теории)

Проводник DOM браузера показывает какой класс у искомого элемента
получается что это SVG и нужно заменить содержимое одного из его `<text>...</text>`
Пишем `$('.c3-chart-arcs-title').text(x);`
в данной задаче работаем с первым элементом, а в общем случае это коллекция..
но сейчас усложнять не будем

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['Поле 1', 5],
      ['Поле 2', 25],
      ['Поле 3', 70],
    ],
    type: 'donut',
    onmouseover: function(d) {
       $('.c3-chart-arcs-title').text(d.value);
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false, // отключаем меню при наведении на столбцы
    title: function(d) {
      return 'Data ' + d;
    },
  },
  donut: {
    label: {
      show: false //отключаем вывод процентов на самих столбцах
    },
    //title: function () {return x + '%'}, // не понятно как обновлять переменную
    title: 'тут проценты от label',

  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pubnub/eon/master/lib/eon.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/pubnub/eon/master/lib/eon.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.13.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

А можно и даже лучше, если `jQuery` не подключена к проекту, использовать возможности базовой библиотеки D3.js
заменяем код на
`d3.select('.c3-chart-arcs-title').text(x);`

осталось разобраться с `legend`
обработчик похожий только он `id` возвращает для `item`

```js
var datain = [
  ['Поле 1', 5],
  ['Поле 2', 25],
  ['Поле 3', 70]
];

var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: datain,
    type: 'donut',
    onmouseover: function(d) {
      donut_title(d.value);
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: false, // отключаем меню при наведении на столбцы
  },
  donut: {
    label: {
      show: false //отключаем вывод процентов на самих столбцах
    },
    title: 'тут проценты от label'
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    item: {
      onmouseover: function(id) {
        var dataitem = datain.filter(function(rowdata) {
          return rowdata[0] == id;
        })[0];
        chart.focus(dataitem[0]);
        donut_title(dataitem[1]);
      }
    }
  }
});

function donut_title(x) {
  d3.select('.c3-chart-arcs-title').text(x);
}
```

```html
<!-- Load c3.css -->
<link href="https://rawgit.com/c3js/c3/master/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<!-- C3 зависит от D3, поэтому, пожалуйста, загрузите D3 тоже. -->
<!-- C3 работает совместно с D3 предыдущей на данный момент 3-й версией -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/c3js/c3/master/c3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Информация о [C3.JS](http://c3js.org/reference.html)
Информация о [D3.JS](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md)

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое. Я чет вообще не в ту степь полетел с мыслями. Спасибо огромное!